# php datetime doesn't match with my windows system

Tags: php

I used `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` to get current date time format but the result doesn't match with my Windows system.

Example:

```
<?php
echo "Current date time: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br />";
?>
```

The sample code displaying result:

> Current date time: 2012-05-30 01:58:21

But my Windows system date time is 2012-05-30 09:56:04

I have tried using `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore')` function to get my region datetime **and it's work but I want it set default in my php.ini.**

For example: **(it's work)**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
echo "Current date time: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br />";
?>
```

I have also tried to set default value in php.ini that is `date.timezone = ""` changed to `date.timezone = "Asia/Singapore"` but doesn't work.

I use Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit and php-5.3.13-Win32-VC9-x86. Does anyone know how to match between these value?

Comment: try to echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s A T") to see what it output

Comment: I have tried 'echo "Current date time: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s A T")."<br />";' and the result is 'Current date time: 2012-05-30 03:01:24 AM UTC'

Comment: Now I got warning like this: Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in E:\Web Development\projects\datetime\datetime.php on line 9

Comment: @Manellen Please update your question with the new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_default_timezone_set` will supersede php default timezone setting, without needing to restart anything.
But in your case it did not work. that's weird. Try this as this is my last resort:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
//date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s A T", time());
?>
```

**UPDATES:**

Since what you need is a default php timezone and permanent solution without using `date_default_timezone_set`, following the few simple steps below:

1. Create a file called `phpinfo.php` with one line content `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Run http:// localhost /phpinfo.php and look for `Loaded Configuration File`. Example value `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2\bin\php.ini`
3. Open the above `php.ini` file with a notepad. Look for the `[Date]` and modify as below:

   ```
   [Date]
   ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
   ; http://php.net/date.timezone
   date.timezone = Asia/Singapore
   ```
4. Save it and restart your apache. Run again your `datetime.php`. Or you can also verify directly from `phpinfo.php` under a h1 header `date` by making sure the default timezone is read as "Asia/Singapore" like below: 
   [image]

Comment: using `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');` is work but how to make it default on my php.ini so in the future I'm not set it again? <br /> I thought I should edit my question

Comment: Now I got error like this `Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in E:\Web Development\projects\datetime\datetime.php on line 9`

Comment: the warning is because you set to an undefined `date.timezone`. Please follow my latest updated guide above.

Answer (score 2):

- Are you running that script via webserver (e.g., Apache) or CLI? Apache needs to be restarted after making changes to php.ini.
- Are you sure that you are editing the correct php.ini file?  Create a phpinfo() page and verify the path to the php.ini file in the output.

Comment: I'm running that script via apache webserver and I have restarted the server after change php.ini. Still doesn't work

Comment: Now I got error like this<br/>`Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in E:\Web Development\projects\datetime\datetime.php on line 9`

Comment: What did you change to get that warning?

Comment: Previously I have changed the php.ini but now is work. It's complicated, when I change the date.timezone = "" in php.ini I see this warning and I try again using You-Qi and work, realy strange. Thanks for your guide before Phoenix

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the default Timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
```

**UPDATE**:

Have you restarted server after change PHP ini?

Comment: Yes that's right I need to define the default Timezone before using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s A T") ` but how to make it set default on my php system itself? example php.ini

Comment: Now I got error like this `Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in E:\Web Development\projects\datetime\datetime.php on line 9`